# Deploying Reliable Service instances with varying config

Tags: azure-service-fabric

How you create multiple instances of the same reliable service buto deploying them with varying configuration? For instance, I want 10 services of the same type. However, I want to have a custom configuration parameter in Settings.xml called groupName or something. Now I need 3 with one value, 4 with another and the last 3 with another.

I believe this is possible but I haven't found any documentaction on how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by creating multiple instances of one applicationtype. Use powershell 'New-ServiceFabricApplication' for that. 
Override specific configuration parameters using its '-ApplicationParameter' option.

example
Add overridable configuration value in settings.xml:

```
<Parameter Name="MySetting" Value="" MustOverride="true"/>
```

Override configuration value in service manifest:

```
<ConfigOverrides>
  <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
    <Settings>
      <Section Name="MyServiceConfiguration">
        <Parameter Name="MySetting" Value="[SettingParameter]"/>
      </Section>
    </Settings>
  </ConfigOverride> 
</ConfigOverrides>
```

Don't forget to declare the parameter:

```
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name="SettingParameter" DefaultValue="GroupA"/></Parameters>
```

Create the application instance:

```
New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName fabric:/MyApplication -ApplicationTypeName MyApplicationType -ApplicationTypeVersion 7.6.5 -ApplicationParameter @{ "SettingParameter" = "GroupB" }
```